# koin default implementation without name reference

Tags: android, mobile, dependency-injection, kotlin, koin

I have 2 Retrofit Clients one of them default and second one has different implementation like (base URL, interceptors etc... )

i need to inject default client without using name reference

first client :-

```
single<Retrofit> {
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(RemoteConstants.BASE_URL)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(APIResponseConverter())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
        .client(get())
        .build()
    }
```

Second Client:-

```
single<Retrofit>("retrofit_second") {
        Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("diffrent url")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
                .client(get("SecondOkHttpClient"))
                .build()
}
```

My way to inject

```
val myModule = module {
    factory { get<Retrofit>().create(FirstAPI::class.java) } // Why Koin did not figure it without providing its default name !?
    factory { get<Retrofit>("retrofit_second").create(SecondAPI::class.java) }
    factory<IMyRemoteDataSource> { MyRemoteDataSource(get(), get()) }
    factory<IMyRepository> { MyRepository(get()) }
    factory { MyUseCase(get()) }
}
```

the result is :

```
        Multiple definitions found for type 'class retrofit2.Retrofit' - Koin can't choose between :
    Single [name='retrofit_second',class='retrofit2.Retrofit']
    Single [name='Retrofit',class='retrofit2.Retrofit']
```

Why Koin did not get the default Retrofit instance without providing its default name (Retrofit ) !?

```
factory { get<Retrofit>().create(FirstAPI::class.java) }
```

Comment: This looks more like an issue (i.e. feature request) you can open in **Koin** repository

Comment: @OmarMainegra I added it. https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/322

Comment: https://medium.com/@farshidabazari/android-koin-with-mvvm-and-retrofit-e040e4e15f9d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right @Eslam. Current behavior (as of `koin:1.0.2`) is when you don't specify the dependency name, it is [treated](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/koin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/koin/dsl/context/ModuleDefinition.kt#L185) as an empty string. And [then](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/koin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/koin/core/instance/InstanceRegistry.kt#L58) the definitions get [filtered](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/koin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/koin/core/bean/BeanRegistry.kt#L60) by class name:

```
fun searchByClass(clazz: KClass<*>): List<BeanDefinition<*>> {
    return definitions.filter { clazz in it.classes }
}
```

As a result you get both of your definitions, which results in the above mentioned error: `Multiple definitions for class ...`.